# Address got auto created in ActiveMQ Artemis even auto-create-addresses value is "false"

Tags: wildfly, activemq-artemis

I am using Wildfly 14 and ActiveMQ Artemis 2.7.0. 
Configuration of ActiveMQ Artemis in Wildfly standalone-full-ha.xml as below.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:4.0">
    <server name="default">
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <remote-connector name="remote-artemis1" socket-binding="remote-artemis1"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="remote-artemis1" ha="true" client-failure-check-period="1000" retry-interval="1000" reconnect-attempts="-1"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="remote-artemis1" ha="true" client-failure-check-period="1000" connection-ttl="-1" call-timeout="300000" client-id="Wildfly-14" retry-interval="1000" reconnect-attempts="-1" use-global-pools="false" thread-pool-max-size="120" transaction="xa" user="admin" password="admin" min-pool-size="40" max-pool-size="200" initial-connect-attempts="10"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

Created connection factory using **java:/JmsXA** in my application
Below are the code for lookup queue/topic in external artemis

```
Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
env.put(JmsUtils.JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY_URL, "tcp://localhost:61616");
context = new InitialContext(env);
(Destination) context.lookup("dynamicQueues/TestQueue");
```

In ActiveMQ Artemis 2.7.0, I have added following settings under `address-settings`:

```
<auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
<auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>
```

When I deploy my application in Wildfly and try to send message on `TestQueue` then my application will create address successfully even though there is no queue exists in `broker.xml` also I have added setting of `auto-create-addresses` as **false**

Can you please provide me solution, if queue does not exist in `broker.xml` then application throws exception.

Comment: How are you confirming that the address is getting automatically created? Also, what `match` are you using for your `<auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>`?

Comment: Login to artemis admin console and checked that address is created even though auto-create-addresses is false

Comment: You didn't answer my second question. What `match` are you using for your `<auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>`?